# Adjusting the browser zoom size

Tags: html, css

Now I have read a couple SO answers about this question, but I have tried them all with no luck. I have found that that website I have been developing on I have had my browser zoom set differently than the default zoom size. I want to accommodate for people that may still have the default zoom size. Being the curious guy that I am, I wondered if I can change the browser size for that window. If the user wants to zoom in or out after they load page that's up to them, but I wanted to see if there was a way to have a default zoom so that it looks how it should.

Some things that I have tried

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Tried this and literally nothing changed on my browser. I set it to default just to check as well, and even after changing all the numbers it never made a difference.

So I came across a different way to do this, in CSS and same thing nothing happens at all.

```
@-viewport
{
zoom: .5;
}
```

So now I am on SO. I'm not even 100% positive that what I am trying to do is the right way to do it. I could be doing something completely off track, so that's why I am asking this question.

Basically, how do I achieve a default zoom size for the size on load, and what is the syntax for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `user-scalable=no`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

And:

```
@-webkit-viewport   { zoom:100%; }
@-moz-viewport      { zoom:100%; }
@-ms-viewport       { zoom:100%; }
@-o-viewport        { zoom:100%; }
@viewport           { zoom:100%; }
```

Comment: yeah i just tried it, still nothing. Might just redesign everything smaller =[

Comment: Updated my answer. Try =no rather than =0, and add the CSS.